# SOQL query to get records with start date in next 90 days

Tags: soql

I'm trying to build a dynamic soql where a date field has to be in the next 90 days so the soql i wrote is as below , however this isn't working:

```
SELECT Id FROM X__c WHERE Start_Date__c = NEXT_90_DAYS.
```

Any help as to where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

It's because you're querying the objects with a date **equals** to the next 90 days.

Try this:

```
SELECT Id FROM X__c WHERE Start_Date__c <= NEXT_90_DAYS AND Start_Date__c > TODAY
```

Comment: You also need `Start_Date__c > TODAY`, no?

Comment: @AdrianLarson You're right !

Comment: Or alternatively, you could just use the `=` operator. Depends on what you're going for.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're getting a but confused with `LAST_N_DAYS:90` where `SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:365` would be valid.

But, in addition to Martin Lezer's answer, you can also use:

```
NEXT_N_DAYS:90
```

> For the number n provided, starts 00:00:00 of the current day and continues for the next n days.

For instance:

```
SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate > NEXT_N_DAYS:15
```

You can check out [the docs here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The field I'm concerned with is a Date field and not a Date time and that's the problem because checking against NEXT_90_DAYS is not right since date literals like these deals with date time both.
This is how i solved this:

```
Date next90Days = Date.today().addDays(90);
SELECT Id FROM X__c WHERE Start_Date__c <=: next90Days
```

Comment: Date literals in soql work for date time as well.